# ASP .Net 'Get' Web API Controller url with input parameters having # special character not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Get Controller accepting userName and Pwd parameters.
if password is having # special character, then its not working, but it works for other special characters(!$@..).
In postman # is replaced with %23.

url: https://localhost:8003/api/EmpInfoTest?userName=Afzal&userPwd=Afzal#123

```
public  class EmpInfoTestController : ApiController
    {
 public string Get(string userName, string userPwd)
        {

     //line1
     //line2
     //return
}
}
```

solution on internet to use  Server.UrlEncode(url).

Let me know how and where to use the urlEncode.

Thanks,
Afzal.

Comment: can you let me know how to use the UrlDecode for the input parameters, Thanks.

Comment: With the documentation for `UrlDecode` - here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Aside from the glaring security issues, the problem with `UrlDecode` is that tou have to know that the parameters are url encoded, or a password that includes `%23` could be mistaken as `#`. A better solution is to change the action method to `POST`, and submit the credentials as a form submission, encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (i.e. default)

Answer (score 0):

## The browser will not pass the `#` character.

Through testing, sending a request to the server, it is found that the `#` parameter and the following characters are not available in the back-end method.

**So the conclusion is that urlencode should be processed when the request is sent.**

**My sample code ( I use ajax ):**

[image]

[image]

**My test result:**

[image]